# How can I preserve session information when redirecting from one subdomain to another?

Tags: php, session, redirect, subdomain

I'm programming with PHP.

I want to redirect https://abc.example.com/blah1/blah2 to https://www.example.com/blah1/blah2  but I don't want to redirect https://abc.example.com redirect to https://www.example.com

Is it possible while preserving session information across the redirections?

Thank you.

Comment: I hope I edited the question correctly.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I want. I just can not post link as a new comer -_-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can continue using the redirects as you have them now, but adjust your `session.cookie_domain` to use the top-level domain (e.g. example.com).  You can do this by using [`session_set_cookie_params`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) or setting [`session.cookie_domain`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain) in your php.ini file (or in a .htaccess file after `php_value` directive).  That should allow your session information to persist across all sub-domains of your site.

Comment: what if I just use session without cookie?

Comment: Sessions in PHP by default use cookies to store the *session id*.  Then when the visitor loads a page, PHP uses that ID to fetch the data associated with that session.  So when you create a session, you are also creating a cookie, although the only data it contains is the session id.  It is possible to use sessions without a cookie, however it passes the session id around as a query parameter which has some serious security flaws.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using a cookie for the session ID, then you need to set the cookie for a common domain. If you are using `www.example.com` and *`foobar`*`.example.com`, you need to set the cookie for `example.com` to have it valid for both `www.example.com` and *`foobar`*`.example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use apache's Redirect you can try

```
RedirectMatch /(.+) https://www.domain.com/$1
```

with PHP it would be

```
<?php


    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != "/") {
        header("Location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        exit;
    }

?>
```

About session being invalidated, like Gumbo says, have the cookie issued for the main domain name instead of the specific ones.

Comment: `REQUEST_URI` is *never* empty. It always starts with at least `/`.

Comment: And also it seems I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you can redirect by posting (POST) your sessionid to a new domain and store your session data in mysql with your own session handler.

Answer (score -2):

Use a javascript redirect.

Comment: What happens when a user has Javascript disabled?